# get request data from Flask redirect

Tags: python, http, flask

I have to create a small web app in Flask which contains an API and also an interface and I'm facing the following problem:
This would be how i handle a GET request:

```
@app.route('/member/<id>', methods=['GET'])
def member_get(id):
    member = cursor.execute(f"select * from members where id={id}").fetchone()
    if member is not None:
        return to_json(member), 200
    else:
        return 'Not found', 404
```

And I would like to create some small forms with which I could do GET,POST,PUT,DELETE operations.

This would be how I get the data from the form:

```
@app.route('/dashboard', methods=['POST'])
def dashboard_post():
    id = request.form['get_id']
    return redirect(url_for("member_get",id=id))
```

**My question is** how can I get the data from the API method without actually redirecting to that page?
More precise, can I call somehow `redirect(url_for("member_get",id=id))` and get the response data directly? (if I print the return of the redirect method it only shows the request status)

I assume one solution would be using the **requests** module, but is there a way to do it directly in Flask?

Comment: Hi, your question isn't really clear. Can you try explaining again?

Comment: hello @NoCommandLine, there is now an answer to the question that pretty much answers my question. maybe you can understand better from the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, an API should always return a response in a format that is **consistent** and **predictable**. The code for `member_get` returns JSON in case of success but plain text in case of failure. This is not okay. You should return JSON always, with the appropriate HTTP status code. Here you are using 404 to express Not found, this is good.
You can use the jsonify function in Flask for that. And maybe normalize the response, so that is always has the same **shape**, whether the member ID is found or not.

Otherwise, parsing the response from your API will be harder because it is not consistent depending on the scenario.

Second point, if I understand it right: if you want to invoke the route '/member/' from within your API, you could simply do:

```
return member_get(id)
```

You call the function that is attached to the route, not the route itself. Of course you could actually fetch the page with the requests module but this is unnecessary, since the function is available internally.

Comment: this is exactly the behaviour I was looking for! thanks for the response and for the tips.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear, but as I understand, (1) you think you have to get your form data from one view and send it to another view to do operations. (2) you are not familiar with flask request and flask-wtf. and maybe (3) looking for a way to do this without refreshing or redirecting the page.

1. You don't need to separate your GET and POST methods. instead you can integrate both in one view.

   ```
   @app.route('/member/<id>', methods=['GET', 'POST])
   ```
2. To handling data, you can use flask request.

   ```
   from flask import request
   ```

and access to data in your view like this:

```
id = request.form.get("idField")
```

but you can also use Flask-WTF to simply make and handle forms.
with Flask-WTF your view would be like this:

```
from app.forms import SearchForm

@app.route('/your-endpoint', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def yourView():
    form = your_form()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        id=form.idField.data
    return render_template('test.html', form=form)
```

the condition `form.validate_on_submit()` checks if you are submitting a from or you just opened it. if you submit a form and it's data are valid based on validators defined in your form, the code runs. else just renders the template and returns the page.

To learn how to make forms with Flask-WTF I recommend reading [this](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-iii-web-forms) article:

3. If you don't want to refresh the page or redirect it after submitting the form, you can use AJAx on your page.